# How to get a full copy of a dump file while it is still being created?

Tags: bash, backup

1. Every hour the main machine takes a minute to produce a dump file of
   about 100MB.
2. A backup machine copies that, using scp, also hourly.
3. Both actions are triggered by cron to start at the same minutes past the hour.
4. The copy often contains only part of the dump file.

Although I could change the cron on the backup machine to happen 5 minutes later, that rather smells of cheating.

What is the correct way around this problem?

Comment: If it takes a minute for dumping you could add sleep to copy command. `sleep 60 & copying.sh`

Answer (score 2):

Leverage `fuser` to determine if the file is in-use; something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
MYFILE=myfile   #...change as necessary
while true 
do
    if [ -z "$(/sbin/fuser ${MYFILE} 2> /dev/null)" ]; then
        break
    fi
    echo "...waiting..."
    sleep 10    #...adjust as necessary
done
echo "Process the file..."
```

Comment: OK, nice suggestion, I didn't know about fuser.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can modify the source code of the programs, you can have the "dumper" output a second file indicating that it is done dumping.

```
1. Dumper deletes signal file
2. Dumper dumps file
3. Dumper creates signal file
4. Backup program polls periodically until the signal file is created
5. Backup program deletes signal file
6. Backup program has complete file
```

Not the best form of IPC but as its on another machine... I suppose you could also open a network connection to do the polling.

Comment: Yes good suggestion. I am using an md5 of the dump file for my signal file. I force at least a one second delay before calculating the md5 then I can check if the dump file is finished by checking whether the signal file is newer than the dump.

Comment: Good thinking - takes care of the integrity check in the same step.

Answer (score 0):

Very quick and very dirty:

```
my_file=/my/filename  

while [[ -n "$(find $my_file)" -a -n "$(find $my_file -mmin -1)" ]] ; do
  echo "File '$my_file' exists, but has been recently modified. Waiting..."
  sleep 10
done

scp ...             # if the file does not exist at all, we don't wait for it, but let scp fail
```

Comment: Yeah I've taken a little from what you suggest here, mainly the sleep to wait and check again for signal file - see my comment to ose's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy the file from the main node to the backup node in one script:

```
1. dumpfile
2. scp
```

Then it's guaranteed that the file is finished before the scp call.

Comment: I don't want the main machine to push the dump to the backup. I only want the backup machine to tack the dumps. That way the main machine doesn't need to know where the backups are going.